# Lengths of breaks and labels differ R convert numerical months into factors

Tags: r

I've worked with cut() function in simple cases, but this is the first time I need to convert numerical numbers [1 up to 12] into labels as factors in an additional column of my data frame.

```
labs <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "Jul","Aug", "Sept", "Oct","Nov","Dec")
length(labs) #12
sequence = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
length(sequence) #12
months_df$Month <- cut(months_df$NumericMonth,breaks = sequence,labels = labs)
```

Selecting column of NumericMonth and CompleteDate

```
 Ind NumericMonth CompleteDate
  9     2         1999-02-19        
 15     1         1999-01-08        
 38     6         1998-06-12        
 61     1         1999-01-08        
 76     5         1998-05-01        
 115    5         1998-05-15        
 124    7         1998-07-11
```

**Error:**
Error in cut.default(months_df$NumericMonth, breaks = sequence, labels = labs) : 
  lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ

**Output I want**

A new column with months as factors (with labels) based on NumericMonth

How can I convert numeric months into factors with labels?

Comment: It's a `cut`ting issue - check out `cut(1:12, 1:12)` and `nlevels(cut(1:12, 1:12))`

Comment: Also check out `month.abb`, which is built-in to R - `month.abb[c(3,1,12)]`

Comment: Looked into month.abb, but didn't know how to apply it. It seems that Gavin Simpson in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058393/convert-a-numeric-month-to-a-month-abbreviation has the answer I was looking for. Gavin's answer helped me fix my issue.Thanks!