# Convert month's number to Month name

Tags: r, date

I need to convert this integer vector which contains the number of months in the year to month's name.

for example :

```
1
2
3
```

The expected result should be :

```
January
February
March
```

How can I do this, please?
Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22058393/680068

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can just use `month.name` to change the index of months to its corresponding name

```
month.name[v1]
```

and there is also a 3 character abbreviation for month

```
month.abb[v1]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- sample(1:12, 24, replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you for your response but, it doesn't works when I did like this: `MONTH<-c(1:12)` and then `month.name(MONTH)` . But I get this error `could not find function "month.name"`

Comment: @Rprogrammer  I am using `R 3.4.4` on linux, but. it should also be available in windows OS as I recently used it.

Comment: Yes, as @Ryan mentioned (I didn't catch it, thanks), `month.name` is not a function, it is a default vector of names of month

Comment: Even I do as you said : `> month.name[v1]
Error in month.name[v1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. I think that I should download the `R.3.4.4` version.

Comment: @Rprogrammer  What is the output of `month.name` and here `v1` is a numeric index

Comment: @akrun, I use v1 as `v1<-c(1:12)`.

Comment: @akrun, But I got `Error in month.name[v1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: @Rprogrammer  For me, it is working fine `v1 <- c(1:12);
month.name[v1]
 [1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"     "May"       "June"     
 [7] "July"      "August"    "September" "October"   "November"  "December" `

Comment: @akrun, It's really weird. Note that I am working with `R.3.5.0` and I get the above error. Is it this issue ??

Comment: @Rprogrammer  I heard there are some issues in R 3.5.0

Answer (score 4):

If predefined `month.name` does not work for your language or your special needs, just make a vector of names that is best for your work case like e.g.

```
my.month.name <- Vectorize(function(n) c("Januar", "Februar", "Maerz", 
                                         "April", "Mai", "Juni", "July", 
                                         "August", "September", "Oktober",
                                         "November", "Dezember")[n])

# examples
my.month.name(1)
my.month.name(2)
my.month.name(3:5)
```

This will work for other things than months as well.

Comment: @akrun That is right, it appeared to me as soon as I left the building. I think that this should be enclosed in a function, even if only so that it can be used with the `apply`-family more easily. I did `Vectorize` because usually I'd progress and later add some error checking for sensible or not sensible input and then it would be preferable to deal with each `n` at a time. For example, this function should throw an error when called with negative numbers. Turns out, apart from negative arguments (which are unlikely), `'['` is already reasonable with error checking in the case at hand.

Answer (score 0):

[lubridate](/questions/tagged/lubridate)

```
library(lubridate)

> month(1:3, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
# [1] January  February March  
# 12 Levels: January < February < March < April < May < June < ... < December
```

One advantage of this, over using `month.name`, is that it's given as an ordered factor, which can be useful if you're using data where months may be missing from the data, but important for when you go to plot it.

You're also able to change the locale (using the argument `locale`) if you want to get the months for a different place than the default of your R environment.