# ggplot produce random monthly name on the x-axis in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, axis, lubridate

my sample code- part of this question was answered by @r2evans.

```
    DF <- data.frame(Month = 1:12, Val = runif(12,5,35)) %>% 
          mutate(Month = month.name[Month])

ggplot(DF, aes(x = Month, y = Val))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

the `ggplot` produce the following with `x-axis` starting at different month.
[image]

Comment: `... %>% mutate(Month = month.name[Month])`

Comment: @r2evans I was thinking the ggplot `ggplot(DF, aes(x = Month, y = Val))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")` using the posted sample data would produce plot with `x-axis` starting from `January`. Its throwing random month on the `x-axis`

Comment: (1) You originally asked *"How to change number to monthly name in R"*, so I answered that. (2) Every question that asks about ordering things in `ggplot2` comes down to `factor`. Change it to `mutate(Month = factor(month.name[Month], levels=month.name))`.

Comment: For ggplot axis ordering, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3253641/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12774210/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18401931/3358272; ordering with groups https://stackoverflow.com/q/44350031/3358272

Comment: The month names are _not_ random. They are in alphabetical order. You need to specify the order, as explained by @r2evans.

Comment: You should not completely change a question to get more information. If you have a new, different question; start a new post.

Comment: Thank you all for very helpful suggestions. @r2evan, I am not sure how do I accept your answer? I see there are multiple suggestion for having an answer to this question, I feel its a close match but not exactly what I was looking. So thinking it would still help others looking for solutions to similar problem.

Comment: This question was originally a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607659/convert-months-number-to-month-name, and when you changed it to ggplot2 axis order, the four links in my previous question are all applicable: the combination of `factor` and strictly the need for `levels=` are what you needed, and the first of those four links mention that. (Perhaps the 3rd/4th are less specific to your use here but still good info, imo.)

Comment: That said, thanks for looking to "accept" something, but there's no need, the preferred resolution is close-as-dupe.