# Plotting monthly mean temperature of multiple years in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe:

`> DF2
     Year Month     mtemp
1    2013     1  5.006653
2    2013     2  7.621885
3    2013     3 11.510275
4    2013     4 17.216123

mtemp represents Mean monthly temperature
I would like to plot similar to this : [temperaturepicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9RP6.png)

I have provided data that is limited to 2013-2015. I would like to plot mean monthly temperature from 2013-2015.(In reality I have a data from 2013-2100 that i would like to plot). So  I would like to have an overview of how to achieve a plot similar to the picture I have attached. I am trying in ggplot, to achieve a result but not getting a desired output.  How can I display months as  "jan", "feb", "mar" etc in my x axis?. How can I achieve this in ggplot2?Thanks!

Comment: creating a new variable of type yearmon would be a good start. See as.yearmon from package zoo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a numeric month to a month abbreviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058393/convert-a-numeric-month-to-a-month-abbreviation)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like to do in 2 steps: Create the data summary and the plot it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

**Step 1**

```
summary_data <- DF2 %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(mean_temp = mean(mtemp))

# A tibble: 12 x 2
   Month mean_temp
   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1      4.09
 2     2      7.22
 3     3     12.7 
 4     4     17.5 
 5     5     20.0 
 6     6     22.3 
 7     7     22.7 
 8     8     21.1 
 9     9     19.3 
10    10     15.1 
11    11      9.86
12    12      5.75
```

**Step 2**

```
ggplot(summary_data) +
  geom_col(aes(x = factor(Month), y = mean_temp)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = month.abb[1:12]) +
  labs(title = "Your Title", y = "Your Y Axis", x = "Your X Axis")
```

[image: example output]

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr` in conjunction with `ggplot`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(month_name = case_when(
      Month == 1 ~ "jan",
      Month == 2 ~ "feb",
      Month == 3 ~ "mar")) %>%    # etc., for rest of months
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = month_name, y = mtemp))
```

That should get you started