# Converting a column of integers that aren't in date format already into abbreviated months

Tags: r, date, integer

I'm trying to convert a column of full integers into date format of abbreviated months. The column has numbers like : 01 02 04 15 13. etc. I want these numbers to show the month they correspond to. Could someone please tell me how. the code I'm trying is this:

```
#Changing integers to Month Abbrev.
dets_per_month$monthcollected = as.POSIXlt(dets_per_month$monthcollected, format = "%m", origin = "%m")
```

but I realize the column doesn't have an origin because it's not in date format.

Comment: Could use some more info. What date should 15 be, for example? 
For `i  = 1:12` , you can use `month.abb[i]`

Comment: sorry that was meant to be 12, not 15.

Comment: I assume month 13 is also a mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a numeric month to a month abbreviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058393/convert-a-numeric-month-to-a-month-abbreviation)

Comment: Hey yes 13 was an accident as well. sorry. I thought this answered my question but actually that code isn't working. It's changing to the abbreviated month, but it's not the right month for each number. for example, 01 was assigned april

Comment: Make sure your column is not a factor. If it is use `as.character` first.

Answer (score 2):

```
month.abb[as.integer(dets_per_month$monthcollected)]
```

Comment: How about:
`month.abb[as.integer(as.character(dets_per_month$monthcollected))]`

Comment: @KristenCyr: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This will help future readers who might run into the same problem. It will also give some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the `lubridate` package for all things date-time related. It's a nifty package and has more utility than base R, but YMMV.

```
library(lubridate)
x <- rep(1:12, 2)
lubridate::month(x, label=TRUE)
```

Comment: This gives me an error because it doesn't know how to convert the column into POXIClt

Comment: Hmmmmm. You say in your question that you want "to convert a column of full integers into date format of abbreviated months". The date format part doesn't seem possible -- "Nov" is not a date, it is part of a date. Perhaps you could provide more context for us?


I also wonder if `dets_per_month$monthcollected` is numeric. From your description above, it sounds like a string variable (leading zeros). Perhaps `lubridate::month(as.numeric(dets_per_month$monthcollected), label=TRUE)` will get you closer?