# Updating a numeric column with characters in R

Tags: r

I have a column like this of the Data data.frame:

```
Month
3
6
9
3
6
9
3
6
9
...
```

I want to update 3 with March, 6 with Jume, 9 with September. I know how to do it if I have two months 3 and 10 for example with: `mutate(Data, Month=if_else(Month==3,"March","October"))` How can I do it for three months?

Expected output:

```
Month

March
June
September
March
June
September
March
June
September
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a numeric month to a month abbreviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058393/convert-a-numeric-month-to-a-month-abbreviation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use your numerical month values to access `month.name`, which is R's built-in vector of month names, starting at index 1:

```r
Data <- data.frame(Month=c(3,6,9))
Data$MonthName <- month.name[Data$Month]
Data

  Month MonthName
1     3     March
2     6      June
3     9 September
```

Comment: FYI, `month.name` is a built-in vector that lists the months' names.